# ASP.NET eBanking help

Tags: asp.net

Is there any microsoft starter kit available to learn eBanking project ?
( Ex:  for ecommerce application -> **dashCommerce** ).

Comment: Many starter kits are for demo; be careful about assuming they contain best security practices...

Comment: To Mitch's point: What bank do you work for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be of interest: [Electronic Banking Guidance](http://www.occ.treas.gov/netbank/netbank.htm) (but check your country's rules).

You might be better off purchasing a tried and tested e-commerce framework.